# GNUPlot add labels to scatterplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am making several graphs at once with a perl script which runs gnuplot and outputs png images.

My data looks like:

```
3.57 3.13 2.88 3.38 A1H1'-A1H8
4.95 4.53 4.17 4.89
3.91 3.37 3.11 3.64
3.98 4.22 3.88 4.55 A1H2'-A2H1'
...
```

columns are x, y, y low error, and point label.

GNUPlot input is:

```
set xlabel 'X-Ray Distance (Angstrom)'
set ylabel 'NOESY Distance (Angstrom)'
set title 'r(AAAA) A-Form Correlation'
set terminal png size 1200, 900
set xrange[2:9]
set yrange[2:9]
set output 'correlation_AAAA.png'
plot x title 'NMR = X-Ray', \
     'correlation_AAAA.dat' title 'NMR' with yerrorbars
```

My question is, how can I get the 5th column to show as a label for some points (not all)?
This link: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/2008-02/msg00094.html says it is very difficult (nigh on impossible)

Comment: Have you read the message you linked? Doesn't seem so because it tells you how one can put labels beneath points ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got lost in all of the GNUPlot documentation.  My own fault.

Here is the minimal working solution:

```
set label " A4H8-A3H3'" at 7.42, 2.98
set rmargin at screen 0.92
plot x title 'NMR = X-Ray', \
 'correlation_AAAA.dat' title 'NMR' with yerrorbars
 pause -1
```

the "set rmargin" is necessary so labels don't run off the screen edge.

Thanks for your kind help Christoph.  I was confused when I tried to put "using labels with yerrorbars" which GNUPlot did not like.

Comment: Well, if you want the label to be read from the data file, you can use the `labels` plotting style, which was what I meant :): `plot 'correlation_AAAA.dat' with yerrorbars, '' using 1:2:5 with labels`.